# Universally restrict UITextfield input

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, alphanumeric

How can I restrict input to alphanumeric app-wide? Do I need to subclass UITextField? Can I set that attribute in the appDelegate?

Edit: I'd like to avoid using keyboardType ASCIICapable. Client would like to keep the email keyboard, etc. functionality.

Answer (score 2):

try playing around in the storyboard

.
 [image: attributes inspector]

navigate to KEYBOARD TYPE setting and see if it has the requirement you need.

Comment: I tried using keyboard type ASCIICapable, but I'd like to keep using the email keyboard, etc. for the functionality. I'll update my question. Thanks, though!

Comment: Then try keyboard extensions